# Write conditionals from data returned of an xml parse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help me understand how I would write this.

If i am parsing data from an xml file like:

```
function  parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("ITEM").each(function()
  {
    var foo= $("bar", this).text();
    $("#container").append('<div>' + (foo) + '</div>');
  });
}
```

How would I write a statement like if foo = hello then return goodbye and have that output but otherwise just return foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..try this.

```
function  parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("ITEM").each(function()
  {
    var foo = $("bar", this).text();
if(foo == "hello"){ foo = "goodbye" }
 $("#container").append('<div>' + foo + '</div>');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could have misunderstood, but it sounds like you want a condition inside the callback for each(). Could you do something like:

```
function  parseXml(xml) {
$(xml).find("ITEM").each(function()
var foo= $("bar", this).text(), 
    output; 
if (foo === /[Gg]ood(-)*bye/) {
    output = 'Goodbye';
}
else { output = foo; }
$("#container").append('<div>' + (Output) + '</div>');
```

});
}